# Woher kommt die Redewendung "Weiß der Geier"?

Tags: etymology, idiom

Wieso *Geier*? Soviel ich weiß, es gibt keine Geier in Deutschland. Kommt die Redewendung aus Literatur oder der Volkskunde?

Comment: Es mag sein, dass es gegenwärtig in Deutschland keine Geier gibt, aber das war nicht immer so. Vor ca. 150 Jahren gab es noch Gänsegeier, die in Deutschland gebrütet haben. Auch der Bartgeier dürfte vor längerer Zeit in deutschen Bergen heimisch gewesen sein.
Es ist also auch möglich, dass der Begriff einfach länger überlebte als der Vogel.

Comment: Weiß der Geier wo das herkommt... ;-)

Comment: Es gibt auch Zoos und Reisefreiheit und Einwanderer. Wir haben sogar Worte für Dinosaurier, die Sonne, Einhörner und Gott.

Comment: Siehe ISBN: 9783809430162, Brucker: Was weiß der Geier, Bedeutung und Herkunft von Redewendungen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ich hab's auch nur aus dem Netz, aber: der Geier steht für den Teufel. "Weiß der Teufel" gibt es ja auch als Redensart. Scheint so, dass der Geier als Vogel einen schlechten Ruf gehabt hat und hat.

Gefunden [hier](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/theme197/article2263173.html) mit weiterführenden Erklärungen

In [Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GG05184) steht folgendes zum Geier:

> *[...] auch so dasz dabei eigentlich nur an den **teufel** gedacht werden kann und soll, dessen namen man doch damit zu nennen meidet*

Comment: Dafür spricht, dass man auch "Weiß der Teufel" und "hols der Teufel/Geier" sagt.